# scalatra case t: Throwable => t.printStacktrace()

Tags: java, scala, scalatra

I am just beginning with scala and scalatra. Following the guidline at
http://www.scalatra.org/getting-started/first-project.html

I am running into a compilation error that I am not sure how to handle:

```
[error] /Users/cory/lichen/src/main/scala/ScalatraBootstrap.scala:10: value printStacktrace is not a member of Throwable
[error]       case t: Throwable => t.printStacktrace()
[error]                              ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 13 s, completed Feb 6, 2013 10:11:17 PM
```

I haven't edited any files yet. I am running java 1.7 and scala 2.10.0 on mac os x 10.8.2

Thanks

Comment: I've edited the g8 template to not have this anymore

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the api call should be `printStackTrace()` with a capital *T*.

I wonder if a typo was introduced 19 hours ago in this [commit](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-sbt.g8/commit/738b106795d876634a45363c022b7a86c30d98eb#src/main/g8/src/main/scala/ScalatraBootstrap.scala).

I [left a comment](https://github.com/scalatra/scalatra-sbt.g8/commit/738b106795d876634a45363c022b7a86c30d98eb#commitcomment-2576199) on that line on github. Hopefully the author will notice. Otherwise, you may want to try to fix the typo.